# Compiling program using Math Kernel Library in 64 bit using gcc?

Tags: c, intel-mkl

It appears that with `gcc`, it is only possible to compile programs using Intel's Math Kernel Library in 32 bit mode, as per [installation instructions](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-intel-mkl-2017-getting-started)

```
source /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh ia32 
gcc -m32 example_program.c -lmkl_intel -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -liomp5 -lpthread -lm
```

If I try, for example

```
# Only options are ia32 or intel64
source /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64
gcc example_program.c -lmkl_intel -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -liomp5 -lpthread -lm
```

I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmkl_intel
```

Is it impossible to compile programs using the Math Kernel Library in 64 bit without using icc, Intel's own C compiler?

Edit: additionally, when compiling I get the message

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.199/linux/mkl/lib/ia32_lin/libmkl_intel.so when searching for -lmkl_intel
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.199/linux/mkl/lib/ia32_lin/libmkl_intel.a when searching for -lmkl_intel
```

When compiling with:

```
gcc hertzian_analysis_nd.c -L"/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.199/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/libmkl_intel_ilp64.a" -lmkl_intel -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -liomp5 -lpthread -lm
```

I still get the same error.

Comment: did you specify the `-L` parameter for the `lib.a` directory location?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean. `mkl_intel.a` isn't located anywhere in the mkl installation directory. I do see many folders like compilers_and_libraries, compilers_and_libraries_2018, compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.199, as well as a folder `mkl/lib` which contains many files like libmkl_intel_ilp64.a. Not sure where exactly to link to :S

Comment: Try to add to your gcc command-line `-L"path/to/libmkl_intel_ilp64.a"` before `-lmkl_intel...`, replace `path/to` with the directory location that contains `libmkl_intel_ilp64.a` on your PC.

Comment: Doesn't work, see post.

Comment: Do you get the errors with `/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.199/linux/mkl/lib/ia32_lin` in them after `source /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64`?  Seems like something's wrong in your environment, as that **ia32_lin** directory name looks like "IA **32** bits for Linux".  I'd expect that to be something like `intel64_lin` after sourcing the script with `intel64` as the argument.

Comment: No, sorry, I got just the `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmkl_intel` error.